# Why does Resharper flag this as "access to modified closure"?

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm sorry if this is a repeat question.  I see many questions here about "modified closure", but none seem to address what I'm seeing.

Resharper 2016.2 is flagging both my use of "b" and "i1" inside the lambda expression as "access to modified closure".  I don't think it should.  I never use either b or i or i1 anywhere else in the program.  Both are declared within the loop -- in fact, i1 was created by Resharper to resolve the modified closure issue with i.  I can try to resolve it with i1 and it will just create an "int i2 = i1" and still give me the warning on i2!  Surely this is not right.  What am I missing here?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Button b = new Button();
    int i1 = i;
    Invoker.SyncInvoke(b, () => { b.Text = "number " + i1; });
}
```

EDIT:
This has to be a bug.  At one point in a certain source file (at line 424, to be precise) are these three lines:

```
        var collapsed = daSheet;
        int numrows = collapsed.GetLastNonEmptyRow(NonEmptyItemFlag.Data);
        int numcols = collapsed.GetLastNonEmptyColumn(NonEmptyItemFlag.Data);
```

If I paste the above snippet (the for loop above) BEFORE those lines, I get no warning.  If I paste it AFTER those lines, I get a warning about both "b" and "i1".  If I paste it between the 2nd and 3rd lines, I get the warning about "i1", but not b.  That makes no sense.

Comment: No offense to the many smart people who work on Resharper but -- the false positive rate for some of their analyzers is pretty terrible. I don't think you're missing anything; I think this isn't a very good analyzer.

Comment: The use of `Invoker.SyncInvoke` is superfluous; a button is being created and the text is being assigned, yet the button hasn't been added to the controls collection.

Comment: If this code is a simplified example it may have been simplified too much, hard to say for sure though.

Comment: Is this the exact snippet that's causing issues? Because if I paste this into a new project (and create the Invoker class), I don't get the warning at all.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact snippet, and yes it's way oversimplified.  The minimum to get the problem to appear.  Weirdly, if I paste it into a new project or any smaller one, I don't get the warning, but if I paste it into my big project I do.  Every time.  There are no other variables or anything called "b" or "i1" anywhere.

Comment: More info added to post...

Answer (score 0):

" the false positive rate for some of their analyzers is pretty terrible" - your're right^^

In fact Resharper is not that wrong.

Imagine instead of Invoker... you would use sth like this Task.Startnew(...)
I would assume(with only reading the source) that after executing you don't have 10 different buttons, you have only one and this one has the text "number 9".

Because the compiler brings the button and the i1 parameter within the lambda expression close together, it's worth it in general to have a look into the decompiled source code with dotpeek
?

Comment: You're mistaken there.  You will definitely have 10 buttons because you called "new Button()" 10 times.  If you used the loop counter "i" in the lambda, all the buttons would (or might, depending on when the code actually executed) say "button 9".  Creating a locally scoped variable (that gets snagged by the lambda) makes it work right.  Resharper is wrong about this.